# Optional reference array php

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I want to pass optional diferents array in same functions. While I am not passing optional array is working nice but when I pass the optional array this is not saving, when I callback the function the value in array is not updated. It is like the reference to array is not working.

```
function asignarColumna($columnasArray, $nombreColumna, $fila, & $arrayTipo = null)
{
    global $letras;
    $columnasArray[$nombreColumna] = $fila;
    if(func_num_args() > 3)
    {
        $arrayTipo[] = $letras[count($columnasArray)-1];
    }
    return $columnasArray;
}
```

Cases:

```
$columnasArray = asignarColumna($columnasArray,"Impuesto",$fila["Impuesto"]); //okay
$columnasArray = asignarColumna($columnasArray,"KMS. F.ULT. ACT.", $fila["Fecha_ult_act_km"], $dateArray[]);   // not saving values in $dateArray[]
$columnasArray = asignarColumna($columnasArray,"Kilómetros", $fila["Kilometros_finales"], $numericArray[]);   //not saving values in $numericArray[]
```

Comment: `$dateArray[]`. I have no idea what you're trying to do with that in the context of a function arg.  Get rid of the `[]`?

Comment: get rid the [] is working, Im new in php and i didnt understand how to indicate a php an array.

Comment: You can use type hints if you have type expectations for args ([docs here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)) but otherwise you just pass variables. In this case it makes more sense imo to initialise the variables before these lines with e.g. `$dateArray = [];` if they don't exist yet, and depending on context.

Comment: Okay I get it, thank you!